# Lazy registration with sinatra and datamapper

Tags: ruby, validation, sinatra, datamapper

I have a user model in my Sinatra application that requires the user to enter an email a password and a confirmation of the password. Something along the lines of this:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,                 Serial
  property :email,              String, :required => true, :unique => true, :format  => :email_address,
  property :name,               String
  property :hashed_password,    String
  property :salt,               String  
  property :created_at,         DateTime

  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of     :password
  validates_length_of       :password, :min => 6
  validates_confirmation_of :password
end
```

This works fine and all except I want to be able to create a user and associate other models to that user without the user entering anything but a name. After a while the user will have created a group and other users that are also associated with that group. 
Then I need the user to be able to enter an email address and a password and put those in the created fields in the database. I guess the validation doesn't occur until I save the user object I have created but I need to save the users in the database without the email and the password of course If they want to be able to login they will need to provide the information necesarry for that.

Do I create my own validation methods or is there a way to make DataMapper validate sometimes (eg. for one post request but not for another) and sometimes not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://datamapper.org/docs/validations and "Contextual Validations" - maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is "Stop asking questions and RTFM". Seems like a good answer. Thank you :)